# Cooking meat on Shabbat using Kinetic energy, or non-conventional ways

Tags: halacha-theory, cooking-bishul, meat, contemporary-halacha, bishul-akum

Putting all jokes (and Purim Torah) aside, a person successfully demonstrated cooking both steak and chicken using a machine that slaps the meat continuously ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHFhnnTWMgI)). Albeit they claimed it tasted very chewed up, it was still edible and slightly good. [Here](https://www.wired.com/story/how-many-times-do-you-have-to-slap-a-chicken-to-cook-it/) and [here](https://www.futurescienceleaders.com/surrey1/2019/03/14/how-hard-do-you-have-to-hit-a-chicken-to-cook-it/) are some more articles about doing so.

As far as Halacha is concerned, what is the status of such meat? May a non-Jew "cook" meat for a Jew this way? May someone "beat" raw meat on Shabbos and "cook" it (assuming they didn't move it, and it was done manually)? Does the concept of cooking include non-thermal methods?

Answer (score 1):

R Daniel Braude ([Learn Shabbos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304), pp. 120ff) writes that it is only cooking if using a heat source and if it is the normal way of cooking. **Since "meat slapping" doesn't have a heat source and is not the normal way to cook, it wouldn't be prohibited.** This of course assumes no one turns on the machine on Shabbat.

Specifically, he writes

> - The Torah prohibition of cooking is transgressed by using fire and those things that derive their heat from fire because that is the
>   normal way to cook. However any heat source that gets red-hot is also
>   considered fire
> - Cooking under the sun is permitted, as this kind of cooking is not normal and therefore not called cooking in a Halachic sense (but
>   *Chazal* prohibited cooking using anything that derives its heat from the sun as it is very similar to something that derives its heat from
>   the fire)
> - A microwave could theoretically be permitted (ignoring electricity for the moment) as it does not actually have a heat source. However it
>   is prohibited since it is (now) the normal way to cook
> - The prohibition of cooking only applies when the heat is capable of causing the food to become *yad soledes bo*

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).